# testing nested routes with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I'm trying to test routes with rspec.   The following gives an error of "Expected block to return true value".

I'm not sure what I am missing.  Through a browser I can post to this url and it is successful.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Routes

```
resources :forum_topics do
  resources :forum_sub_topics
end
```

Test:

```
it "recognizes and generates nested #create" do
  { :post => "/forum_topics/1/forum_sub_topics" }.should route_to(:controller => "forum_sub_topics", :action => "create", :forum_topic_id => 1)
end
```

Comment: Try running `rspec` with the `-b` option to get a backtrace of the error.

Comment: I don't think `:forum_topic_id` will actually be an integer. Try `:forum_topic_id => '1'`

Comment: Rob S has the exact answer, I'll try -b as well just for fun.

Comment: This answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295721/rspec-controller-specs-for-2-level-nested-resources

Answer (score 10):

Well nobody officially answered my question, so I will :)

```
{ :post => "/forum_topics/1/forum_sub_topics" }.should route_to(:controller => "forum_sub_topics", :action => "create", :forum_topic_id => 1)
```

It comes down to :forum_topic_id => 1 not being equal to :forum_topic_id => "1"  Perhaps my PHP days have crept up to bite me. Strings and Integers :)

Comment: When I did this, the id (1) needed to be a string "1"

Answer (score 8):

I know it comes down to the same thing but if you'd like to shorten your code you could also do:

```
{ :post => "/forum_topics/1/forum_sub_topics" }.should route_to("forum_sub_topics#create", :forum_topic_id => 1)
```

I find it easier to read.

Comment: This actually worked for me as opposed to the answer from @recursive_acronym. The answer from recursive seems to look at the parent controller. Anyway, thanks for the info!