# Testing nested resource controller with rspec in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I am trying to make a test for a controller for a nested resource.

The nesting is like this in the routes.rb

```
resources :cars, :only => [:index, :destroy, :show] do
  resources :car_subscriptions, :only => [:new, :create], :as => :follow_subscriptions
end
```

I'm trying to test the create action most specifically:

```
describe CarSubscriptionsController do

  def valid_attributes
    {:car_id => '1', :user_id => '2'}
  end

  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new CarSubscription" do
        expect {
          post :create, :car_id => 1, :car_subscription => valid_attributes
        }.to change(CarSubscription, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "assigns a newly created car_subscription as @car_subscription" do
        post :create, :car_subscription => valid_attributes
        assigns(:car_subscription).should be_a(CarSubscription)
        assigns(:car_subscription).should be_persisted
      end

      it "redirects to the created car_subscription" do
        post :create, :car_subscription => valid_attributes
        response.should redirect_to(CarSubscription.last)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

It's actually a part of the scaffold generated by rails script. And I only modified the valid_attributes and the post in the first 'it'

And the output is this:

```
  1) CarSubscriptionsController POST create with valid params creates a new CarSubscription
     Failure/Error: post :create, :car_id => 1, :car_subscription => valid_attributes
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:car_id=>"1", :car_subscription=>{:car_id=>"1", :user_id=>"2"}, :controller=>"car_subscriptions", :action=>"create"}
     # ./spec/controllers/car_subscriptions_controller_spec.rb:34:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/car_subscriptions_controller_spec.rb:33:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It's the same error for all 'it's.

I've tried removing the `:as => :following_subscriptions` from the routes.rb file but the same problem.

I have actually split up the resources of car_subscriptions so `index` and `destroy` are in not nested, and `create` and `new` are nested in `:cars`

I don't want to use hard coded paths like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942362/322253) but if it is the only way, I can give it a try:

```
{ :post => "/forum_topics/1/forum_sub_topics" }.should route_to(:controller => "forum_sub_topics", :action => "create", :forum_topic_id => 1)
```

**EDIT**

Oh, and my rake routes looks like this:

```
car_follow_subscriptions_da POST   /biler/:car_id/car_subscriptions(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"car_subscriptions", :locale=>"da"}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what `rake routes` provides, I guess you should replace:

```
 post :create, :car_id => 1, :car_subscription => valid_attributes
```

with:

```
 post :create, :car_id => 1, :car_subscription => valid_attributes, :locale => "da"
```

Comment: Yeah! You're right, that's strange, this should be better documented in [RubyOnRails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#what-to-include-in-your-functional-tests) !

Comment: I'd say you should set a default locale setter in your application controller

Comment: And it's in the Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale :)

Comment: In my application, `I18n.locale` is available even if not set in the ApplicationController as described in the link. Means the application works even if the locale is not provided in the URL, but the tests fail...

Comment: If I add it to the controller, then remove it from the rspec, it still throws the RoutingError

Comment: mmm, is the locale within brackets in your routes.rb?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5835/discussion-between-cristian-and-apneadiving)