# Rspec: Controller specs for 2 level nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

my routes.rb

```
  namespace :magazine do
   resources :pages do
     resources :articles do
       resources :comments
     end
   end
  end
```

While writing controller specs for Comments:

```
describe "GET 'index'" do
    before(:each) do
     @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
     @page = FactoryGirl.build(:page)
     @page.creator = @user
     @page.save
     @article = FactoryGirl.create(:article)
     @comment_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:comment, :article_id => @article )
   end
it "populates an array of materials" do
  get :index, ??
  #response.should be_success
  assigns(:comments)
end

it "renders the :index view" do
  get :index, ?? 
  response.should render_template("index")
end

end
```

Any idea how to give the page and article reference to get :index ?? 
 if I give : get :index, :article_id => @article.id
    Error I get is below:

```
 Failure/Error: get :index, :article_id => @article.id
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:article_id =>"3", :controller=>"magazine/comments"}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your route requires at least two IDs: the comment's parent article, and the article's parent page.

```
namespace :magazine do
  resources :pages do
    resources :articles do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
end

# => /magazine/pages/:page_id/articles/:article_id/comments
```

**All parent IDs** must be provided for this route to work:

```
it "renders the :index view" do
  get :index, {:page_id => @page.id, :article_id => @article.id}
  # [UPDATE] As of Rails 5, this becomes:
  # get :index, params: {:page_id => @page.id, :article_id => @article.id}
  response.should render_template("index")
end
```

Comment: So if I want to test a negative situation - page_id is not in the request - then how do I do that?

Comment: That will cause a routing error. Rails guide says "resources should [*never* be nested more than 1 level deep](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)."

Comment: @gg_s it will not cause an error. In fact as you can see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting Rails Guide says you *should* not do it, not that you can't.

Comment: @BartlomiejSkwira There's no way that could happen. Unless there's a bug in Rails router.

Answer (score 9):

With Rails 5 the params API changed:

```
get :index, params: { page_id: @page.id, article_id: @article.id }
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/request-specs/request-spec#specify-managing-a-widget-with-rails-integration-methods