# In rspec file, I am getting => Error: ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches xxxxxxx despite valid routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, routes, rspec-rails

I am very very new to testing and new to rails (less than 1 year of experience). Please keep this in view before answering.

I have a model `recipe` which belongs to a `source` and `source` belongs to `client`.

Route is:

`client_source_recipes GET /clients/:client_id/sources/:source_id/recipes(.:format) recipes#index`

I am trying to test this:

```
RSpec.describe RecipesController, :type => :controller do

# Prerequisites go here (mentioned at the end of the question)

  describe "GET #index" do
    it "assigns all recipes as @recipes" do
      recipe = Recipe.create! valid_attributes
      get :index, params: { client_id: client.id, source_id: source.id, locale: 'cs' }, session: valid_session
      expect(assigns(:recipes)).to eq([recipe])

      # Commented below are different ways I tried but failed:

      # visit client_source_recipes_path(client.id, source.id, locale: 'cs')
      # visit "/client/#{client.id}/source/#{source.id}/recipes?locale=cs"
      # get client_source_recipes_path, params: { client_id: client.id, source_id: source.id, locale: 'cs' }, session: valid_session
      # get client_source_recipes_path(client.id, source.id, locale: 'cs')
    end
  end
end
```

Prerequisites for test:

```
  login_user         # defined - works well

  let(:client) { create :client }                                         # defined in factories 
  let(:source) { create :source, warehouse_id: 1, client_id: client.id }  # defined in factories

  let(:valid_attributes) {
    { name: "name", source_id: source.id }
  }

  let(:valid_session) { {"warden.user.user.key" => session["warden.user.user.key"]} }   # works well in other tests
```

Why do I get the error of route when same route is being used everywhere else?

Errors:

```
 Error: ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"recipes", :params=>{:client_id=>"1", :source_id=>"1", :locale=>"cs"}, :session=>{"warden.user.user.key"=>[["1"], "$2a$04$bobnhLAlKEsxZtlJheY64."]}}

 Error: ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"recipes", :action=>"/clients/1/sources/1/recipes?locale=cs"}

 Error: ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"recipes", :action=>"/clients/1/sources/1/recipes"}

# etc. etc. i.e. errors are more or less the same
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using:
  `ruby '2.3.8'`
  `gem 'rails', '3.2.22.5'`
  `gem 'rspec-rails'`
  `gem 'factory_bot_rails', '>= 4.0.0'`

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295721/rspec-controller-specs-for-2-level-nested-resources. Try by removing params as said in that answer

Comment: @Aarthi Thanks for directing to it but it actually asks to add both ids in params which I guess I already am doing.

Comment: if I write: `get :index, { client_id: client.id, source_id: source.id, locale: 'cs' }, session: valid_session`, I puts the response in terminal, then the response contains: `warning: ActionController::TestResponse#respond_to?(:to_ary) is old fashion which takes only one parameter`.
It only is a warning but I thought I must mention it.

Comment: @Aarthi Ah now I get what you meant. I could not understand that you meant the word params literally and not the params as a whole :-) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK!

I have 'spent' like 5 hours pondering on this but could not do it in any way and now I found out that the only issue was syntax:

Wrong (old) syntax (expects params and session as arguments explicitly):

```
get :index, { client_id: client.id, source_id: source.id, locale: 'cs' }, session: valid_session

#or

get :index, params: { client_id: client.id, source_id: source.id, locale: 'cs' }, session: valid_session
```

Right (newer) syntax (accepts params and session as arguments implicitly):

```
get :index, { client_id: client.id, source_id: source.id, locale: 'cs' }, valid_session
```

I hope it saves precious time of other people, unlike me ):